# Is there any way I can get the runtime in masm while using irvine library?

Tags: masm32, irvine32

So I've been trying `getmseconds` function of irivine library but it returns time in ms which by the end of the program is so low that it doesn't even show the difference in eax hence I always get 0. Is there any other function which returns time in nanosecond or any other way I can solve this problem?

Comment: As you are on Windows you could call `QueryPerformanceFrequency` and  `QueryPerformanceCounter` which are 2 APIs to get the most precise timing interval on Windows. It might not be trivial if you start on writing assembly though as you will need to manipulate 64-bit quantity.